# Grid Update Event not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

Error on :: RowIndex not found

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

Below is the Grid row update event....

```
  protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, EventArgs e)  
  {         
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DropDownList ct = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("case_type");
    DropDownList cs = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("case_status");

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE intakesheet SET case_number = @case_number, case_name=@case_name, Case_Type=@case_type, Case_Status = @case_status, assigned_date = @assigned_date, assigned_to = @assigned_to, date_withdrawn= @date_withdrawn, date_delivered= @date_delivered, qc_by = @qc_by,  qc_date=@qc_date, additional_notes = @additional_notes WHERE (case_number = @case_number)", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    con.Close();
    bind();

}

public void bind()
{

    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from intakesheet", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "intakesheet");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: `GridView1.EditIndex = -1;` ? why ?

Comment: So that after poastback dont loose the previous data value.. Can you tell me about [e.RowIndex]......??

Comment: Post the source page also.

Comment: Change  EventArgs to GridViewUpdateEventArgs

Comment: Dont change the question and code as you like. This is not fair. Post it as a question. Moderators kindly look into this type.

Comment: The same i suggested to @AnkitGoyal, Any way in update statement you are passing the id of dropdown , starnge, pass ct, selected index or value. with error handled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

with

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Start a new thread if not related to this topics, if related to this, shoot

Comment: bye the way , if it helped, plz makr it as answer :)

Comment: It is related to same topic.. Let me update the code in the question.

Comment: better to start a new one, becuase such type of mistake usually developers do, so your post can save theirs a lot time

Comment: This is completely different question bro

Comment: @AnkitGoyal: Revert it to the older one. Post this as a new question